# How to extract character component in values and replace the values with -99

Tags: regex, r

My data looks like:

```
VAR_A: 134, 15M3, 2004, 301ME, 201E, 41, 53, 22
```

I'd like to change this vector like below:

```
VAR_A: 134, -99, 2004, -99, -99, 41, 53, 22
```

If a value contain characters (e.g., `M`, `E`), I want to change those values with `-99`. 
How could I do it in R? I've heard that regular expression would be a possible way, but I'm not good at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me you want to replace the values that are not digits, if that is the case ...

```
x <- c('134', '15M3', '2004', '301ME', '201E', '41', '53', '22')
sub('.*\\D.*', '-99', x)
# [1] "134"  "-99"  "2004" "-99"  "-99"  "41"   "53"   "22"
```

Or essentially you could do:

```
x[grepl('\\D', x)] <- -99
as.numeric(x)
# [1]  134  -99 2004  -99  -99   41   53   22
```